# How to Read Csv with Random Formatting C#

Tags: c#, csv

I would like to read CSV file where I am not sure of the format.
So in code, I would like to have presets, for the Format I do know of based on the samples I have so far. SO If I come across a new format I would like to flag it to the user so I can add it to my preset going forward. If the csv does not have a header it must still read the data.  How can I distinguish between headers and no headers? and headers that are a few rows down but still recognize new formats?

Data1

> Total Stock,700,,
>
> Total Cost,26464,,
>
> Name,Service Date,Details,Price
>
> BMW,01/08/2022,Red,4
>
> VW,02/08/2022,Green,5.48
>
> Lexus,03/08/2022,Purple,6
>
> Bently,04/08/2022,Blue,7

Data2

> Name,Details,Price,Service Date
>
> ,,,
>
> BMW,Red,4,01/08/2022
>
> VW,Green,5.48,02/08/2022
>
> Lexus,Purple,6,03/08/2022
>
> Bently,Red,7,04/08/2022

Data3

> Name,Details,Price,Service Date,Weight
>
> ,,,,
>
> ,,,,
>
> ,,,,
>
> BWM,Red,4,01/08/2023,1g
>
> BMW,Red,5.48,02/08/2023,1g
>
> BMW,Purple,6,03/08/2023,1g
>
> BMW,Red,7,04/08/2023,1g

Data4

> ,,Cars Data,,
>
> ,,,,
>
> ,,,,
>
> BWM,Red,4,01/08/2023,1g
>
> BMW,Red,5.48,02/08/2023,1g
>
> BMW,Purple,6,03/08/2023,1g
>
> BMW,Red,7,04/08/2023,1g

Data5

> BWM,Red,4,01/08/2023,1g
>
> BMW,Red,5.48,02/08/2023,1g
>
> BMW,Purple,6,03/08/2023,1g
>
> BMW,Red,7,04/08/2023,1g

C#:

```
string filePath = "C:/Cars/Car1.csv";

bool IsCar2Valid(List<string> headers)
{
    if (headers.Count != 4)
        return false;
    // Check all required columns are present
    if (headers?[0] != "Name")
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (headers?[1] != "Details")
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (headers?[2] != "Price")
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (headers?[3] != "Service Date")
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool IsCar1Valid(List<string> headers)
{
    if (headers.Count != 4)
        return false;
    // Check all required columns are present
    if (headers?[0] != "Name")
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (headers?[1] != "Service Date")
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (headers?[2] != "Details")
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (headers?[3] != "Price")
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// Check if file exists.
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    try
    {


        CsvConfiguration csvConfiguration = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        {
            HasHeaderRecord = true,
            Delimiter = ","
        };

        // Read column headers from file
        CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(File.OpenText(filePath), csvConfiguration);
        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();

        List<string> headers = csv.HeaderRecord.ToList();

        var hasheader = IsCar1Valid(headers) || IsCar2Valid(headers);

        // Read csv into datatable
        System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();

        foreach (string header in headers)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn(header));
        }

        if (hasheader)
        {
            // Import csv
            while (csv.Read())
            {
                System.Data.DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();

                foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
                {
                    row[column.ColumnName] = csv.GetField(column.DataType, column.ColumnName);
                }

                dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Read data that does not have headers
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Format - " + filePath + " needs adding to preset");
    }
}
```

Comment: Seriously, tell whoever created those things by hand to clean up their 5 different Excel files. CSV is a specific simple text format, there's no "random" formatting. What you posted looks like an attempt to save different *manually created* Excel files as text, hence the empty cells in separator lines in examples 2 and 3. Sample 1 includes a full report header, Sample 5 has no header while Sample 4 has a skewed and incomplete header line. Never mind the *bad* date format

Comment: BTW I have to import Excel files from 40 different companies, each with its own layout. Sometimes they sent "CSV" files that look just like the examples - Excel files saved as text. I ended up using *Python* instead of .NET so I can read the entire file into a DataFrame and check the columns, handle optional columns, start dropping empty lines, or for cases like #1, skip rows lines until I found the expected first column and reloaded the frame from that point onward.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The files are coming from different sources which cannot be changed. hence why I am planning to try and identify the format and read acordindly

Comment: Doesn't change the fact these aren't CSV files, you have 5 formats and CsvHelper can't handle such disparate text files easily. Your company is asked to pay the cost of fixing its partners' bad formats. Clearly they know they have to send data a certain way but none did so and some did it worse than others

Comment: At least with Pandas and a VS Code notebook you can load the file into a Dataframe, inspect it, modify it and see the changes immediately. The closest in C# would be the somewhat half-baked [Microsoft.Data.Analysis Dataframe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/getting-started-dataframe) and Polyglot Notebooks in VS Code. You still need to understand how Pandas Dataframes work though to understand what the .NET Dataframe does and Polyglot Notebooks aren't as advanced as Python Notebooks.

Comment: In CsvHelper, **assuming** the ideal format is fixed (ideal, as in known but not implemented), you could use use callbacks like BadDataFound, ShouldSkipRecord, PrepareHeaderForMatch etc to skip the empty rows, ignore the extra header rows and possibly even fix skewed headers.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand its bad formatting but Why is it not CSV? Is it because the Header is not on the first line?

Comment: CSV means Comma Separated Values, not headers, footers and separator lines. It's a *simple* data exchange format, with an optional line containing column names and then one line per data row, with values separated by commas. It's the alternative to fixed width text files, where each field has a fixed width. Only #5 is an actual CSV file. All others are Excel files saved as text

Comment: It's precisely because CSV is used for data exchange that it doesn't have complex headers and separators. Real usage is lax, but not *that* lax. No system would produce Sample #1 and expect another system to use it. Someone clearly saved their Excel as text, or exported their report as "CSV" without bothering to remove headers and footers. At least you're lucky - they didn't include *page* footers!

Comment: CSV was never an official standard but [RFC4180](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) specifies what web sites should return if they use the `text/csv` content type.

Comment: "Shi* in => Shi* out", as we Germans say. Sanitize your input _before_ ingesting it. Don't try to solve two problems with one solution. Divide and Conquer. 2 Problems, 2 Solutions.